# What is this R code doing?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a file "d" that has posting date column in normal date format and PP.sales column. "sos" means sum  of sales and I understand na.rm removes NA values and its keeping all the rows for defined criteria.

```
d <- d[, j = .("sos" = sum(PP.Sales, na.rm = T)),
             by = .(Profit.Center, month(Posting.Date), year(Posting.Date))]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is `data.table` syntax.
This creates a new summary data table. It summarizes data so that every row is the `PP.Sales` sum for each unique combination of `Profit.Center` value per month of `Posting.Date` and year of `Posting.Date`.

`month` takes only the month of the date, and `year` does the same for year. So, if for example `Profit.Center` has the values {1,2,3}, `Posting.Date` has only {may, june} and `Posting.Date` has only {2014,2015,2016} and all combinations exist, than the final `d` will have 18 rows - 1/may/2014, 1/june/2014 etc.. each with the column `sos` that would be the sum of all `PP.Sales` for that specific combination.

Edit: I would create a new table `newd <- d...`, or else you will lose data.